# Code for calculating max profit

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Recently I came across [this](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/BUFFALOES) problem in the IARCS website.

My approach to this problem was like Ramu has to trade or do nothing , for a given day , and since he can only keep 1 buffalo , he has to sell if he has 1 or to buy if he doesnt.And if I can calculate all the possible combinations , I can easily determine he highest profit. But my code doesnt seems to work it is providing with outputs a little bit higher than what is expected and also get stuck sometimes with bigger testcases , after trying it for 3 days,can anyone guide me a little bit in the right path?

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

int bestTrade(int arr[], int size, bool toTrade, int visits, int day) {
  if (day < size - 1) {
    day = day + 1;
    if (visits > 0) {
      if (visits % 2 == 0) {
        int visitsT = visits - 1;
        int trade = bestTrade(arr, size, true, visitsT, day) - arr[day];
        int nothing = bestTrade(arr, size, false, visits, day);
        if (nothing > trade) {
          return nothing;
        } else {
          return trade;
        }
      } else {
        int visitsT = visits - 1;
        int trade = bestTrade(arr, size, true, visitsT, day) + arr[day];
        int nothing = bestTrade(arr, size, false, visits, day);
        if (nothing > trade) {
          return nothing;
        } else {
          return trade;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  int n, k;
  std::cin >> n >> k;
  int market[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> market[i];
  }
  k = (k / 2) * 2;
  int maxProfitT = bestTrade(market, n, true, k--, 0);
  int maxProfitN = bestTrade(market, n, false, k, 0);
  if (maxProfitN > maxProfitT) {
    std::cout << maxProfitN << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << maxProfitT << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code through a reformatter to make it more readable: http://format.krzaq.cc/  you should consider using one of the styles listed there.

Comment: comments also..

Comment: stack overflow is for asking specific questions not for "i'm kinda lost".   If you have a specific question ask it, but this will likely be closed as being too broad.

Comment: what do you mean? I have already provided it

Comment: Have a look at this link. It might help you. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-profit-by-buying-and-selling-a-share-at-most-k-times/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any problem concerned with `dynamic programming`, think of it in this way:

If you know the maximum profit for at most `k` transactions till the `(i-1)th` day, will you be able to figure out the maximum profit for at most `k` transactions till the `ith` day??

Think... The answer is `Yes`!!!!

Say, the maximum profit for at most `k` transactions till the `(i-1)th` day is `best(k,i-1)`. You need to find out `best(k,i)` for any `i<n`.

If you choose not to do any transaction on the `i-th` day, so `best(k,i)` is same as `best(k,i-1)`. If you do want to make a transaction, then `best(k,i)` = max(value[i] - value[j] + best[k-1][j]), j from 0 to i`

So, finally the `DP` formula turns out to be:

`best[k][i] = max(best[k][i-1], max(value[i] - value[j] + best[k-1][j]), j<i`)

For a working code, you can have a look [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-profit-by-buying-and-selling-a-share-at-most-k-times/)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks man , it did my job after spending hours working on my notebook and wasting pages by drawing tables.